# {Soap UI+ mulesoft} integration for Regression

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui, jenkins-groovy, mulesoft

As part of regression suite I need to trigger the automation soap UI  suite post new build is triggered, but I dont have idea to integrate these tools together,

I am not able to find any plugin for soap UI/ready api, so kindly assist me on this....

Answer (score 0):

Mule applications use Maven as a build tool so you can integrate SoapUI tests as part of the Maven build phase. Here is some info on the maven plugin:

https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/maven/index.html

Googling Maven Soap UI also returns blog posts on setting this up and some example github repos.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps-- 
1. Write your test cases in SOAP UI and export the test suite XML.
2. create a maven project and use your test suite details to configure the below POM file.

```
                    <projectFile>soapUi-TestSuite File Location</projectFile>
                    <testSuite>TestSuiteName</testSuite>
                    <endpoint>endpoint URL</endpoint>
```

3. run - `mvn clean test`

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>RegTesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>RegTesting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RegTesting</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!-- Plugin repository for test suites generated via soap UI -->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFile>soapUi-TestSuite File Location</projectFile>
                    <testSuite>TestSuiteName</testSuite>
                    <endpoint>endpoint URL</endpoint>
                    <printReport>true</printReport>
                    <junitReport>false</junitReport>
                    <outputFolder>target</outputFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>  ```
````

Comment: let me check this and come back to you...can we run whole soap ui project xml ??? using maven project ?? I am new to this maven so assist me on this.